# Load url whithout passing adress bar

Tags: php, transactions

Sorry firsly for my poor english...
I want to send data to an url and for security reasons, I would like to know how to "load" without using the bar address.
Something like this:

```
   <form action="???.php">
<input name="customer" id="customer"> </ input>
<input name="amount" id="amount"> <input>
<input type="submit" value="send"> <input>

</ form>
```

https://www.mysite.com/transfer.php?username=myusername&password=mypassword&to=customer&amount=10

by clicking on the "send" button, I would load the page to transfert 10 from my account(myusername) to the customer account.whithout the address bar because the password appear in the url.
Ps: the password would not be encrypted
thanks

Comment: Why are you sending a password via get and not via post data!?! ps hiding the address bar doesn't really increase security...there are plenty of other ways to find the address of the page you are on.

Comment: Please read up about html forms and the difference between POST and GET.

Comment: Sorry!My where to know how i can load a url without send it to the bar address, not hot to define and use a form or Post and Get Method.  I see that i can use a cript and a Div with Ajax.Thanks for your participation

Answer (score 2):

```
<form action="pageToPostTo.php" method="post">
```

now if you click send no variables are in the url, but you can read em in pageToPostTo.php using `$_POST["customer"]` and `$_POST["amount"]`

Good luck

Comment: Sorry!My where to know how i can load a url without send it to the bar address, not hot to define and use a form or Post and Get Method.  I see that i can use a cript and a Div with Ajax.Thanks for your participation

Comment: Ah, that was not really clear to me :) Come back to us when you need help on setting up Ajax! Good luck

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<form action="yourfile.php" method="POST">
  <input name="customer" id="customer"> </ input>
  <input name="amount" id="amount"> </input>
  <input type="submit" value="send"> </input>
</ form>
```

All data will be pass to another page without displaying in URL.

Comment: Sorry!My where to know how i can load a url without send it to the bar address, not hot to define and use a form or Post and Get Method.  I see that i can use a cript and a Div with Ajax.Thanks for your participation

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you could use the POST method to submit your form, instead of using the default GET.

You do this like so:

```
    <form action="???.php" method="POST">
    <input name="customer" id="customer"> 
    <input name="amount" id="amount"> 
    <input type="submit" value="send"> 
    </form>
```

This will allow you to use `$customer = $_POST['customer']` in your PHP instead of `$_GET['customer']`. This way, the form values aren't visible in the URL.

If you really want to forego the address bar, you could use cURL or Ajax to submit the form (mind you, Ajax requests are still visible with tools like Firebug).